# Netlogo BehaviourSpace: Recording only max value of a variable

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I want to run simulation in which I am interested in the value of a variable `participation-rate`. Because of the stochastic nature of other variables in the model this variable often varies. So what I want to do is run the model X times and record the maximum value of `participation-rate` (at the end of each run) after comparing each run with one another. How should I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To record the max value of a variable over a run, you should create a global variable to store it. Initialise it in the setup step (or set it in the first timestep to the current value). Within each time step (eg during the go procedure) you simply compare the current value to the existing stored max value and replace it if the current value is higher.

If you want to compare a value across runs, you need to use the BehaviorSpace tool to run the model multiple times and store output. You can have it report the max value calculated as above, or if it is a variable that never decreases, you don't need to calculate the max, you can simply report the value it has at the end of the run (one of the BehaviorSpace settings - every tick or end of run). Then analyse in your data package of choice.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I just want the value of the variable after the run is completed (i.e. the model is in equilibrium) and want to compare these values between all the different runs. In the model the variable 'participation-rate' starts of high and lowers with each tick. I am thus only interested in the 'end' value.  Using your method will just return the starting value of the variable. Any other thoughts?

Comment: No, my method will return the maximum it achieves during the run. But see other revisions for different problem.